# Cache nested results

Tags: graphql, apollo

In my app, an user might request which friends did a specific action:

```
query($id: Int) {
  post(id: $id) {
    likes {
      id
      name
      photo
    }
  }
}
```

But that means re-fetching the id, name and photo data for the same objects for different posts (since the server doesn't know what I already have cached). What strategy I could use to try leverage the cache here?

Only thing I can think of is in the query above I only request the id field and have separate queries for the name and photo and try to batch those.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way in GraphQL to share objects in the same result object graph returned. You have actually answered your own question. By normalizing the resultant graph of objects using IDs, it does reduce the amount of JSON you'd be transmitting back to the client. However, it requires the clients to request the data in a different way. For example,

```
query($id: Int) {
  post(id: $id) {
    likes {
      id
    }
  }
  likesByPostId(postId: $id) {
    id
    name
    photo
  }
}
```

In GraphQL, we let the clients make the decision on how to optimize the data fetching. The server simply returns the data in the shape the client requests. So you can't really decide for the clients.